# Different appWidgetProviders for different Android version

Tags: android, android-resources, appwidgetprovider

I'm still new to android so this is probably a pretty simple question, thanks.

I've build a widget which currently only support android 3.1+ because it's resizable, and I would now like to make it support earlier android versions too. I know I can create a values folder for e.g. android sdk version 14 be naming it values-v14 ( right?). And I just want to know if I can do this for the xml folder containing the appWidgetProvider file as well?

If so:

I was thinking I would have the 2*2, 2*3, 3*3, etc. widgets for earlier android versions then 3.1, and resizable for 3.1+. So to do this would I then just create a default XML folder for the non-resizable and then an XML folder named like XML-v12 including the resizable widget-properties.
And then does this folder apply to all newer android version or just sdk v12?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've build a widget which currently only support android 3.1+ because
>   it's resizable

This is not true. Setting your appwidget to be resizable does not make it incompatible with earlier versions. Android versions below HC will simply ignore this.

If you want to create widgets in different form factors then you have to create an `appwidget-provider` XML file, a receiver and a `AppWidgetProvider` for each widget.

Of course you can avoid code duplication by creating a base `AppWidgetProvider` and then extending that one to add features, width/height or other customizations to it.

Comment: okay thanks very much, and if I create folder named XML-v12 will all android versions newer then v12 then load the contents of this folder or does it only apply to android v12?

Comment: You *can* create a xml-v12 folder, but it's not really necessary since you can use new attributes and they will be ignored in older versions. But to simply answer your question: yes, you can.

Comment: Okay thank you very much! And I want to do this, because I don't want the 3x3, 3x4... widgets displayed on a newer android device where the resize option is available